# Windows Phone7 Share data among applications

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

I searched everywhere and wondering whether any posible way available for share data among applications within the mobile phone itself. What I basically meant by that is, if there any way that can create a file from one application and allow other applications to access that file.

The problem is, If we save the file in application's isolated storage, then any other application won't be able to access it.

For example a scenario like this. One application produce a file and store it in a public location within the phone and later using the email client application need that file to be sent as an attachment.

Really appreciate any guidance/ help over this task. Thanks in Advance...!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there's currently no way to share data between applications on Windows Phone. For this, you'll have to rely on an external server. Depending on what your apps are doing, you may want to consider using skydrive or dropbox integration to share the files.

Comment: Hi KooKiz, Thanks for the quick response. Oh is that So. The task is to create a PDF file within the phone and to send this as an email attachment. Will it allow to upload pdf files if I try a way of Skydrive integration. This POST decribes that Word, excell files can not transfer this way.

Comment: The problem is that the Windows Phone e-mail creation task doesn't allow the app to add an attachment. There isn't much you can do: either find a library to send e-mails, or create a webservice that will send the file by e-mail, or add skydrive integration and send the skydrive sharing link.

Comment: hi people
i heard Windows phone 8 support some inter app communication, but not able to find much on it. can any one provide something useful regarding this.