# Share database of files among different Windows Phone Apps

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Phone7 Share data among applications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335632/windows-phone7-share-data-among-applications)

I have an application which will have two different versions which can be installed simultaneously on a Windows Phone device.
For that, I would like to share the same database for both applications. Is that possible?
I've searched a lot on the internet, but I could not find anything but the Isolated Storage Files and Local Database.

Thanks

Comment: It does not look to be possible without an external server of the shared data: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335632/windows-phone7-share-data-among-applications

Answer (score 0):

Data cannot be shared between applications even in a database. You will need to have a web server/azure service running with the database.

The database on the server should be able to workout the differences between the two different versions of the app and return the appropriate data for each.

If you are a small business user you could apply to the BizSpark program and get some free Azure hosting.